# Access 2013 Split database didn't move links to SQL Server views and Excel to backend

Tags: ms-access

The database I just split had links to SQL Server views and Excel worksheets. These didn't move to the backend during the split process. I can manually add them to the backend but then they don't appear in the front end. Is this possible or do I need to leave these as links in the frontend database?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Are there any reasons why you need those links in the backend?

Comment: The main issue is that having a link to Excel seems to be causing issues when multiple people have the database open even though the link is only used to update another table once a day first thing in the morning. The table contains a list of employees and the stores they are responsible for. I thought it was easier for the manager to re-arrange staff on the spreadsheet than to do so within the database but I may need to re-think that. A make-table query then turns this linked table into a static table to allow for properties to be changed inc adding a primary key.

Comment: Then you may not need to keep the link to Excel.  Here is a query which pulls from a sheet named *"link_me"* in a workbook named *"temp.xls"*: `SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:\share\Access\temp.xls].[link_me$];`  Get the connection string you need by inspecting the `.Connect` property of your linked Excel sheet.  Once you have the `SELECT` working, convert it to an *"append query"* to add its data to your Access destination table.

Comment: @HansUp thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try and let you know how I get on.

Comment: @HansUp that worked a treat and def gives me ideas on how to proceed. One question, initially I omitted the $ at the end of the sheet name and it threw an error. What does the $ signify?

Comment: I'm not sure about `$` details.  I add it to sheet names sort of by reflex.  However a more reliable way is to link the sheet and then examine `CurrentDb.TableDefs("your_Excel_link").SourceTableName`  That way, you can see how Access recognizes it.

Comment: @HansUp awesome, thanks again. I did some Googling and someone suggested that a string with $ means a sheetname whereas the string on its own is a range name. Don't know if that's true or not.

Comment: Aha!  You can check that out by linking to a named range and then inspecting `.SourceTableName`